# flask pagination object_list not defined

Tags: flask, flask-peewee

I am trying to paginate results in my Flask app with peewee model but get this error:

`...
    File "/home/pi/ehome/main/app.py", line 148, in financeAll
    return object_list('/financeAllTrans.html', trans_list)
    NameError: name 'object_list' is not defined`

If I use render_template instead of object_list it works (obviously not paginated). I can't find any clues on google :/

model.py

```
class Finance(object):
    def __init__(self):
            finDB.get_conn()

    def get_all_transactions(self):
            return transactions.select().order_by(transactions.trans_date.desc()).limit(30)
```

app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MODEL'] = model.DHTData()
app.config['MODEL2'] = model.Finance()

@app.route("/financeAll")
def financeAll():
    trans_list = model.Finance().get_all_transactions()
    return object_list('/financeAllTrans.html', trans_list)
```

.html

```
{% for transaction in trans_list %}
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{ transaction.id }}" id="{{ transaction.id }}" value="{{ transaction.id }}">
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="trans_date" value="{{ transaction.trans_date }}"></div>

...                     

{% endfor %}
     </div>
{% if page > 1 %}
    <a class="previous" href="./?page={{ page - 1 }}">Previous</a>
{% endif %}
{% if pagination.get_page() > page %}                                          
    <a class="next" href="./?page={{ page + 1 }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}
```

Thank you

Comment: I was missing
    "from playhouse.flask_utils import object_list" now i get no error, and no results

Comment: {% for trans in object_list %}